# How to extract the name of the columns corresponding to the top 20% values in a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe of this type:

```
   i1  i3  i4  i9  i14  i16  i17  i18  i19  i20  i22  i26  i27  i28
0   4   2   1   4    1    3    3    4    2    2    4    1    4    3
```

and I have to extract the name of the columns whose values are in the top 20% of all values in the row.

The result would be as follows:

```
[i1,i9,i18,i22,i27]
```

the I need to itereate the same procedure over other rows of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
top20 = df.ge(df.quantile(0.8, axis=1), axis=0)
top_cols = top20.apply(lambda x: x.index[x], axis=1)
```

Example result:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(1, 5, (5, 10)),
                      columns=[f"i{i}" for i in range(10)])
>>> df
   i0  i1  i2  i3  i4  i5  i6  i7  i8  i9
0   4   4   2   4   2   4   4   3   2   4
1   2   3   4   2   2   3   1   1   4   1
2   3   2   2   1   2   2   3   1   2   4
3   3   1   1   3   3   4   2   2   1   3
4   3   2   3   2   4   1   4   2   4   2

>>> top20 = df.ge(df.quantile(0.8, axis=1), axis=0)
>>> top20
      i0     i1     i2     i3     i4     i5     i6     i7     i8     i9
0   True   True  False   True  False   True   True  False  False   True
1  False  False   True  False  False  False  False  False   True  False
2   True  False  False  False  False  False   True  False  False   True
3   True  False  False   True   True   True  False  False  False   True
4  False  False  False  False   True  False   True  False   True  False

>>> top20.apply(lambda x: x.index[x], axis=1)
0    Index(['i0', 'i1', 'i3', 'i5', 'i6', 'i9'], dt...
1                  Index(['i2', 'i8'], dtype='object')
2            Index(['i0', 'i6', 'i9'], dtype='object')
3    Index(['i0', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5', 'i9'], dtype='o...
4            Index(['i4', 'i6', 'i8'], dtype='object')
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wasn't precise in my questions, there can also be negative values in a row. How do I update your code to consider positive values only (i.e. >0)?i0  i1  i2  i3  i4  i5  i6  i7  i8   i9
0   -4   4   2   4   2   4   4   3   -2   4
1   2   -3   4   2   2   3   1   1   4   1
-2   -3   2   2   1   2   2   3   1   2   4
3   3   1   -1   3   3   4   2   2   1   3
-4   -3   2   3   2   4   1   4   2   4   2.      
in the first row, we must consider only  4   2   4   2   4   4   3   4 and then  extract the top values or sort by value.

Comment: @AndreaLongoni That is still too vague, and a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas [quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

`0.8 = 1 - 0.2`

```py
df.columns[df.loc[0,:] >= df.loc[0,:].quantile(0.8)]
```

```
Index(['i1', 'i9', 'i18', 'i22', 'i27'], dtype='object')
```

---

As suggested by @Nko3, more generic way to do this is to apply the formula for each row-

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x >= x.quantile(0.8),1).dot(df.columns + ', ').str.strip(', ')
```

```
0    i1, i9, i18, i22, i27
dtype: object
```